# Lancia Delta Integrale Fuel Pump

Tags: fuel-system

I have a Lancia Delta Integrale with a suspected fuel pump problem. I tried to start the car by spraying some Bradex Easy Start into the air intake. It fired for one or two revolutions then stopped. I disconnected the fuel line and cranked the car but no fuel came out however, it did in the past when there was a fissure in the same pipe! As the car has been parked up for about 4 months, what could have happened in the meantime to cause the problem?

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the fuel pump. What could go wrong is anybody's question. I have little knowledge of the Integrale, so don't know if it has an electric or mechanical fuel pump. You didn't give a year of the vehicle, whether it's the 8V or 16V version (though I doubt this will affect any answers). Any other information you can give us?

Comment: It is a 16V from 1991.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track - it'll be either a problem with the fuel pump or one or more of the fuel lines.

Does it have an in-line fuel filter? If so, is that clear? Are the rubber fuel lines in good condition - it might be worth replacing them as a matter of course, as new lines are cheap.

If it is an electric pump, you ought to be able to test it fairly easily, by switching it on and listening to it - also check the wiring to make sure it is getting power!

Mechanical pumps are harder obviously, the easiest way to test them is to remove them from the car and work the lever manually. The Integrale is injected isn't it - does it have two pumps for low and high pressure?

Comment: It think that it only has one pump and a pressure regulator.

Comment: The problem was the fuel pump. First of all I checked the relays and found two linked to the immobilizer that didn't seem to be working. After replacing them I checked that the fuel pump was receiving power. It was but not pumping fuel so removed it and verified on the bench that it was not pumping fluid.